# Does a Muslim woman with urinary incontinence need to change her pad before each prayer?

Tags: salat, women, taharah, najis, incontinence

There's various online fatawa around which describe the effect of urinary incontinence on salah prayer (e.g. IslamWeb [1](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85661), [2](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=344443); [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/06/20/urinary-incontinence-and-wudu/); [Zamzam Academy](http://www.zamzamacademy.com/2010/09/incontinence-and-prayer/); MuftiOnline [1](http://muftionline.co.za/?q=node/374), [2](http://muftionline.co.za/node/7195), [3](http://muftionline.co.za/node/7415); Islam Q&A [1](https://islamqa.info/en/39494), [2](https://islamqa.info/en/66074), [3](https://islamqa.info/en/117053)).  They usually state that ablution (wudu) is required before each salah, and should be performed after the time for prayer has started.  However, they don't seem to address this question:

**Question**: Does a Muslim woman with urinary incontinence need to change her pad before each prayer?

A woman with urinary incontinence may absorb the urine using some kind of [pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitary_napkin), which will be kept against her skin.  (Maybe men with urinary incontinence do the same, I'm not sure.)  However, the pad may or may not be enough to keep the impurities away in order to perform prayer.  Obviously, there's a level of impracticality to changing a pad this many times per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that one's garments should be pure for Prayer to be offered in them. In case they are soiled with urine they should be washed with water. Since in this case ablution lasts from prayer to prayer its extended that a piece of cloth will be considered pure from prayer to prayer, and should be washed if it is to be reused. Disposable, absorbent pads didn't exist at the time of the Prophet, but the basic rules are that impurity must be washed away and drying is not enough.

The first [islamQA link](https://islamqa.info/en/39494) mentions this:

> Underwear is purified by washing it. If you single out a clean garment
>   for prayer which you can carry with you, that will be easier for you.
>   If it is too difficult to wash your clothes or change them, then pray
>   as you are.

A couple of washable, reusable cloth pads dedicated for prayer could be the answer. If its too much of a hassle then one can keep on using a single pad.